GCP Vertex AI - Error Submitting Request with Anthropic Claude Models
Environment Details

Cloud Platform: Google Cloud Platform (GCP)
Model Attempting to Use: Claude Sonnet 3.5
Issue Context: Free Trial Credit ($300)

Specific Error Message
"An error occurred while submitting the request. Please check if you have selected a valid GCP project & the Marketplace & Vertex AI API have been enabled for the project."
Reproduction Steps

Select GCP project
Navigate to Vertex AI
Attempt to use Anthropic Claude Sonnet 3.5 model
Encounter error

Observations

Error only occurs with Anthropic Claude models
Other models (e.g., Llama) work correctly
Project appears to have free trial credits available

Troubleshooting Attempted

Verified project selection
Confirmed Marketplace API enabled
Confirmed Vertex AI API enabled

Request for Help
Has anyone encountered similar issues with Anthropic Claude models on GCP Vertex AI? Any specific configuration steps or known compatibility issues?

Using your account in this link you may click the “Enable” button to start using Claude Sonnet 3.5.

Here’s additional public documentation link for Anthropic Code Cookbook: Check out example code for a variety of complex tasks, such as RAG from various web sources, making SQL queries, function calling, multimodal prompting, and more.
